# Write values from loop in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function which generates six random numbers (`areacanvas.length` is 6)
And then paints it on canvas as a array of dots. What I need to do is to  write those canvas values in my HTML file using `.innerHTML`

I don't know how to do it,because the  `window.generatedNumber`  is different after single iteration,how I am supposed to save all six values and then write them on HTML?

```
function generateDotMap() {
            for (let index = 0; index < areacanvas.length; index++) {
                var canvas = document.getElementById(areacanvas[index]);
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                // generate random number 
                window.generatedNumber = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 89) + 10).toString();
```

This is my table:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Answers from input :</th>
    <td id ="one"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <th>Answers from method :</th>
    <td id="two"></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I use the method below to write in HTML values from my textboxes in order to compare the generated values and guessed by user ( daltonism test)

```
function checkHumanInput() {
            clearTimeout(humanInputCheckTimeout);
            if (parseInt(document.getElementById('HUMAN_INPUTT').value) == 1) {
                let liczba1 = document.getElementById('HUMAN_INPUT_1').value;
                let liczba2 = document.getElementById('HUMAN_INPUT_2').value;
                let liczba3 = document.getElementById('HUMAN_INPUT_3').value;
                let liczba4 = document.getElementById('HUMAN_INPUT_4').value;
                let liczba5 = document.getElementById('HUMAN_INPUT_5').value;
                let liczba6 = document.getElementById('HUMAN_INPUT_6').value;
                document.getElementById('one').innerHTML="Values given by user " + liczba1 +"," + liczba2 +","+ liczba3 +","+ liczba4 +","+ liczba5 +","+ liczba6 +"."  ;
                document.getElementById('two').innerHTML="And random numbers? " + +"."  ;
                document.getElementById('HUMAN_INPUT_BOX').style.borderColor = '#00A000'; 
            } else {
                document.getElementById('HUMAN_INPUT_BOX').style.borderColor = '#A00000';
            }
```

The whole  genereateDOtMap method looks like that:

```
function generateDotMap() {
            for (let index = 0; index < areacanvas.length; index++) {
                var canvas = document.getElementById(areacanvas[index]);
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                // white background
                ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
                ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, parseInt(canvas.width), parseInt(canvas.height));


                var canvasCenter = {
                    x: Math.floor(canvas.width / 2) - 20,
                    y: Math.floor(canvas.height / 2) - 20
                };


                // dots array
                var dots = [];

                // generate random number 
                window.generatedNumber = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 89) + 10).toString();

                // number as black text
                ctx.font = 'italic bold ' + (canvasCenter.y + Math.floor(canvas.height / 5)) + 'px "Comic Sans MS"';
                ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
                ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
                ctx.fillText(window.generatedNumber, canvasCenter.x - Math.floor(canvasCenter.x / 7), canvasCenter.y - Math.floor(canvasCenter.y / 16));

                for (var i = 0; i < DOTS_TO_RENDER; i++) {
                    var x, y, radius, j;

                    // loop
                    do {
                        // get point inside of a cricle 
                        var point = getRandomPointInCircle();

                        // radius
                        var radius = getGaussianRandom(DOT_SIZE_mean, DOT_SIZE_var);


                        j = 0;
                        for (; j < i; j++) {
                            if (distanceCheck([point.x, point.y, radius], dots[j])) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    } while (j != i);

                    // get canvas coordinates
                    var hX = point.x * canvasCenter.x + canvasCenter.x;
                    var hY = canvasCenter.x - point.y * canvasCenter.y;
                    var overNumber = ctx.isPointInPath(hX, hY);


                    //   ctx.getImageData(point.x,point.y,ctx.width,ctx.height);
                    //  [redColor, greenColor, blueColor, alpha]
                    var overNumber = (ctx.getImageData(hX, hY, 1, 1).data[0] == 0);

                    if (overNumber) {
                        color = hsvToRgb(HUE_NUMBER + Math.random() * HUE_VARIANCE, SATURATION, VALUE + 10);
                    } else {
                        color = hsvToRgb(HUE_BACKGROUND + Math.random() * HUE_VARIANCE, SATURATION, VALUE);
                    }
                    dots.push([point.x, point.y, radius, overNumber, color]);
                }


                // powiększanie kropek (wypełnienie)
                // sortowanie od najmniejszej do największej, małe powiększane najpierw
                dots.sort(function (a, b) { return a[2] - b[2] });
                for (var pass = 0; pass < 2; pass++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < dots.length; j++) {
                        var small_d = 99999;
                        for (var k = 0; k < dots.length; k++) {
                            if (j == k) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            var d = distanceCalc(dots[j], dots[k]) - (dots[j][2] + dots[k][2] + MIN_DISTANCE);

                            if (d < small_d) {
                                small_d = d;
                            }
                        }
                        if (small_d > 0) {
                            dots[j][2] += small_d;
                        }
                    }
                    dots.sort(function (a, b) { return a[2] - b[2] });
                }
                window.saved_dots.push(dots)
                
            }
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: I don't know exactly what  is it supposed to mean?

Comment: @AdamHeinrich provide with relevant HTML, in a snippet maybe.

Comment: It means that unless we have enough code to reproduce the issue, there will be a heap of guessing before a solution to your issue is found.  Did you read the post in the link?

Comment: I did some changes right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I understand, I have commented out the parts that we do not have information for (i.e. HTML) and I have added the insertion of random numbers to a specified `div` with `id` of `randomNumDiv`

This should be good enough to help you

```js
function generateDotMap() {
  var randomNumDiv = document.getElementById("randomNumbers");

  for (let index = 0; index < 6 /*areacanvas.length*/ ; index++) {
    //var canvas = document.getElementById(areacanvas[index]);
    //var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); // generate random number
    var generatedNumber = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 89) + 10).toString();
    randomNumDiv.innerHTML = randomNumDiv.innerHTML + " " + generatedNumber;
  }
}

generateDotMap();
```

```html
<div id="randomNumbers"></div>
```

Comment: glad I could help